# iOS Redrawing image to prevent deferred decompression resulting in a bigger image

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext, compression, cgcontextdrawimage

I've noticed some people redraw images on a `CGContext` to prevent deferred decompression and this has caused a bug in our app.

The bug is that the size of the image professes to remain the same but the `CGImageDataProvider` data has extra bytes appended to it.

For example, we have a 797x500 PNG image downloaded from the Internet, and the `AsyncImageView`redraws and returns the redrawn image.

Here is the code:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
if (image)
{
    // Log to compare size and data length...
    NSLog(@"BEFORE: %f %f", image.size.width, image.size.height);
    NSLog(@"LEN  %ld", CFDataGetLength(CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage))));

    // Original code from AsyncImageView
    //redraw to prevent deferred decompression
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Log to compare size and data length...
    NSLog(@"AFTER:  %f %f", image.size.width, image.size.height);
    NSLog(@"LEN  %ld", CFDataGetLength(CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage))));

    // Some other code...
}
```

The log shows as follows:

```
BEFORE: 797.000000 500.000000
LEN  1594000
AFTER:  797.000000 500.000000
LEN  1600000
```

I decided to print each byte one by one, and sure enough there were twelve `0`s appended for each row.

Basically, the redrawing was causing the image data to be that of a 800x500 image. Because of this our app was looking at the wrong pixel when it wanted to look at the `797 * row + column`th pixel.

We're not using any big images so deferred decompression doesn't pose any problems, but should I decide to use this method to redraw images, there's a chance I might introduce a subtle bug.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Or is this a bug introduced by Apple and we can't really do anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've discovered, rows are padded out to a convenient size. This is generally to make vector algorithms more efficient. You just need to adapt to that layout if you're going to use `CGImage` this way. You need to call `CGImageGetBytesPerRow` to find out the actual number of bytes allocated, and then adjust your offsets based on that (`bytesPerRow * row + column`).

That's probably best for you, but if you need to get rid of the padding, you can do that by creating your own `CGBitmapContext` and render into it. That's a heavily covered topic around Stack Overflow if you're not familiar with it. For example: [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much. Never knew that `bytesPerRow` would be different from the width in points.